Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree Error FLUTTER
When i tap the color button in add_task_page.dart page app crashes. And When i open the app dont display sqflite table in homepage(homepagepass.dart) also and i'm seeing this error which is this:
(also there is no trouble for sqflite db codes or bindings but i can't understand this error.)
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree.
Codes are here:
main.dart
import 'package:animated_splash_screen/animated_splash_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get_storage/get_storage.dart';

import 'db/db_make.dart';
import 'homepagepass.dart';
import 'notification_service.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  NotificationService().initNotification();
  await DatabaseCodes.initDb();
  await GetStorage.init();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      themeMode: ThemeMode.dark,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: AnimatedSplashScreen(
        splash: Image.asset('images/logo.png'),
        nextScreen: HomePagePass(),
        splashIconSize: 180,
        splashTransition: SplashTransition.fadeTransition,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3)).then((value) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
          CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (ctx) => HomePagePass()));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SizedBox(),
    );
  }
}

homepagepass.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'controllers/task_controller.dart';
import 'notification_service.dart';

class HomePagePass extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePagePass({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePagePass> createState() => _HomePagePassState();
}

class _HomePagePassState extends State<HomePagePass> {
  final _taskController = Get.put(TaskController());
  var notificationService;
  var DatabaseCodes;

  bool toggle = false;

  String formattedDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(DateTime.now());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeModel>(
        create: (_) => ThemeModel(),
        child: Consumer<ThemeModel>(
          builder: (_, model, __) {
            return SafeArea(
              child: MaterialApp(
                debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                theme: ThemeData.light(), // Provide light theme.
                darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(), // Provide dark theme.
                themeMode: model.mode, // Decides which theme to show.
                home: Scaffold(
                  appBar: AppBar(
                    elevation: 0,
                    title: const Text('TODOAPP'),
                    leading: IconButton(
                        icon: toggle
                            ? Icon(Icons.mode_night)
                            : Icon(
                                Icons.light_mode,
                              ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            // Here we changing the icon.
                            toggle = !toggle;
                            model.toggleMode();
                          });
                        }),
                    actions: [
                      IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          icon: Center(
                              child: Icon(Icons.person_outlined, size: 30)))
                    ],
                  ),
                  body: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 10),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
//------------------------------------DISPLAY DATE TIME AND (ADD AN ACTION) BUTTON ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                _addAction(),
                                SizedBox(
                                    height: 60,
                                    width: 50,
                                    child: InkWell(
                                      child: Text(
                                        '+ Add Action',
                                      ),
                                      onTap: () {
                                        Navigator.of(context).push(
                                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                                builder: (index) =>
                                                    AddTaskPage()));
                                        _taskController.getTasks();
                                      },
                                    ))
                              ],
                            ),
//---------------------------DISPLAY OF THE DAYS PART-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                            SizedBox(height: 10),
                            Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  border: Border.all(
                                      color: Colors.black, // Set border color
                                      width: 1.0), // Set border width
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                      Radius.circular(
                                          10.0)), // Set rounded corner radius
                                  boxShadow: [
                                    BoxShadow(
                                        blurRadius: 10,
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                        offset: Offset(1, 3))
                                  ] // Make rounded corner of border
                                  ),
                              child: DatePicker(
                                DateTime.now(),
                                height: 100,
                                width: 80,
                                initialSelectedDate: DateTime.now(),
                                selectionColor: Colors.pink,
                                selectedTextColor: Colors.black,
                                dateTextStyle: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 25,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                    color: Colors.green.shade900),
//----------------------------------THE MOST IMPORTANT THING METHOD IS BELOW THIS********************************--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                onDateChange: (date) {
                                  _selectedDate = date;
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 20),

                            Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.red.shade600,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(52)),
                              child: SizedBox(
                                  width: double.infinity,
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: InkWell(
                                      child: Text(
                                        'SHOW/UPDATE TODOs List BUTTON',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            fontSize: 20,
                                            color: Colors.white),
                                      ),
                                      onTap: () {
                                        _taskController.getTasks();
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  )),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
//-------------------------------------------SHOW DATABASE DATA-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                      SizedBox(height: 19),
                      _showTasks()
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _notificationDisplayCurrent() {
    NotificationService().showNotification(title: 'example', body: 'it works');
  }

  _showTasks() {
    return Expanded(child: Obx(() {
      //return Flexible(child: Obx(() {
      return ListView.builder(

          //shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: _taskController.taskList.length,
          itemBuilder: (_, index) {
            //print(_taskController.taskList.length);
            return Container(
                width: 100,
                height: 50,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.pink.shade900),
                  child: Text(
                    _taskController.taskList[index].note.toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ));
            //_taskController.taskList[index].title.toString())
          });
    }));
  }

  _addAction() {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(
            DateTime.now().toString().substring(0, 10),
            style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 25),
          ),
          Text(
            'Today',
            style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                fontSize: 20,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                color: Colors.red.shade900),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
    ElevatedButton(
        child: Text('add'),
        onPressed: () async {
          await Navigator.of(context)
              .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddTaskPage()));
          _taskController.getTasks();
        });
  }
}

DateTime _selectedDate = DateTime.now();

class ThemeModel with ChangeNotifier {
  ThemeMode _mode;
  ThemeMode get mode => _mode;
  ThemeModel({ThemeMode mode = ThemeMode.light}) : _mode = mode;

  void toggleMode() {
    _mode = _mode == ThemeMode.light ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

add_task_page.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

import 'homepagepass.dart';

class AddTaskPage extends StatefulWidget {
  AddTaskPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<AddTaskPage> createState() => _AddTaskPageState();
}

class _AddTaskPageState extends State<AddTaskPage> {
  final TaskController _taskController = Get.put(TaskController());

  final TextEditingController _titleController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _noteController = TextEditingController();

  DateTime _selectedDate = DateTime.now();
  String _endTime = "10:10 PM";
  String _startTime = DateFormat("hh:mm a").format(DateTime.now()).toString();
  int _selectedRemind = 5;
  List<int> remindList = [5, 10, 15, 30];
  String _selectedRepeat = "None";
  List<String> repeatList = ["None", "Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly"];
  int _selectedColor = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade300,
            appBar: AppBar(
                actions: [
                  IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      icon: const Center(
                          child: Icon(Icons.person_outlined, size: 30))),
                ],
                elevation: 20,
                title: const Text('TODOAPP'),
                leading: SizedBox.fromSize(
                  size: Size(56, 56), // button width and height
                  child: ClipOval(
                    child: Material(
                      color: Colors.white, // button color
                      child: InkWell(
                        splashColor: Colors.green, // splash color
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).push(
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => HomePagePass()),
                          );
                        }, // button pressed
                        child: const Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Icon(
                              Icons.arrow_back_ios_new,
                              size: 40,
                            ), // icon
                            // text
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )),
            body: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    const Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: Text(
                        'Add an Action',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
//-----------------------------------------------TITLE--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    InputFieldCustom(
                        title: 'Title',
                        hint: 'Enter the title',
                        controller: _titleController),
//-----------------------------------------------NOTE--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                    InputFieldCustom(
                        title: 'Note',
                        hint: 'Enter the note',
                        controller: _noteController),
//----------------------------------------------CALENDAR-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                    InputFieldCustom(
                      title: 'Calendar',
                      hint: DateFormat.yMd().format(_selectedDate),
                      widget: IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            _dataGetForUser();
                          },
                          icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_month_rounded,
                              color: Colors.orange.shade800)),
                    ),
//-------------------------------------------TIME BETWEEN--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: InputFieldCustom(
                              title: 'Start To',
                              hint: _startTime,
                              widget: IconButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    _dataGetTime(isStartTime: true);
                                  },
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.access_time,
                                      color: Colors.orange.shade800))),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(width: 10),
                        Expanded(
                          child: InputFieldCustom(
                              title: 'End To',
                              hint: _endTime,
                              widget: IconButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    _dataGetTime(isStartTime: false);
                                  },
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.access_time,
                                      color: Colors.orange.shade800))),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
//----------------------------------------REMINDER PART--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    InputFieldCustom(
                      title: 'Remind Before',
                      hint: '$_selectedRemind minutes',
                      widget: DropdownButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
                              color: Colors.orange.shade800),
                          iconSize: 32,
                          elevation: 4,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 24, color: Colors.black),
                          underline: Container(height: 0),
                          onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                            setState(() {
                              _selectedRemind = int.parse(newValue!);
                            });
                          },
                          items: remindList
                              .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((int value) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                value: value.toString(),
                                child: Text(value.toString()));
                          }).toList()),
                    ),
//----------------------------------------REPEATER PART--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    InputFieldCustom(
                      title: 'Repeat',
                      hint: '$_selectedRepeat',
                      widget: DropdownButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
                              color: Colors.orange.shade800),
                          iconSize: 32,
                          elevation: 4,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 24, color: Colors.black),
                          underline: Container(height: 0),
                          onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                            setState(() {
                              _selectedRepeat = newValue!;
                            });
                          },
                          items: repeatList
                              .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String? value) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                value: value,
                                child: Text(value!,
                                    style:
                                        const TextStyle(color: Colors.black)));
                          }).toList()),
                    ),
//----------------------------------------COLOR PART--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    const SizedBox(height: 8),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        _colorPalette(),
//********************************SAVE BUTTON****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
                        ElevatedButton(
                          child: Text(
                            'SAVE',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            _validateDate();
                          },
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.orange.shade800),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )),
      ),
    );
  }

  _colorPalette() {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        const Text(
          "Color",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 8),
        Wrap(
          children: List<Widget>.generate(3, (int index) {
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  _selectedColor = index;
                });
              },
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8),
                child: CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 14,
                    backgroundColor: index == 0
                        ? Colors.red
                        : index == 1
                            ? Colors.blue
                            : Colors.green,
                    child: _selectedColor == index
                        ? const Icon(
                            Icons.done,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            size: 16,
                          )
                        : Container()),
              ),
            );
          }),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  _validateDate() {
    if (_titleController.text.isNotEmpty && _noteController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      _addTaskToDb();
      Get.back();
      Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePagePass()),
      );
    } else if (_titleController.text.isEmpty || _noteController.text.isEmpty) {
      Get.snackbar('Required', 'Please fill all fields!',
          snackPosition: SnackPosition.TOP,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.warning_amber_rounded,
            color: Colors.red,
          ));
    }
  }

  _addTaskToDb() async {
    int value = await _taskController.addTask(
        task: Task(
      note: _noteController.text,
      title: _titleController.text,
      date: DateFormat.yMd().format(_selectedDate),
      startTime: _startTime,
      endTime: _endTime,
      remind: _selectedRemind,
      repeat: _selectedRepeat,
      color: _selectedColor,
      isCompleted: 0,
    ));
    print("My id is" + " $value");
  }

  _dataGetForUser() async {
    DateTime? _pickerCustom = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
      firstDate: DateTime(2024),
      lastDate: DateTime(2124),
    );

    if (_pickerCustom != null) {
      setState(() {
        _selectedDate = _pickerCustom;
        print(_selectedDate);
      });
    } else {
      print('its null or something wrong');
    }
  }

  _dataGetTime({required bool isStartTime}) async {
    var pickedTime = await _showTimeGet();
    String _convertedTime = pickedTime.format(context);
    if (pickedTime == null) {
    } else if (isStartTime == true) {
      setState(() {
        _startTime = _convertedTime;
      });
    } else if (isStartTime == false) {
      setState(() {
        _endTime = _convertedTime;
      });
    }
  }

  _showTimeGet() {
    return showTimePicker(
        initialEntryMode: TimePickerEntryMode.input,
        context: context,
        initialTime: TimeOfDay(
            hour: int.parse(_startTime.split(":")[0]),
            minute: int.parse(
              _startTime.split(":")[1].split(" ")[0],
            )));
  }
}

task_controller.dart
import 'package:get/get.dart';

import '../db/db_make.dart';


class TaskController extends GetxController {
  @override
  void onReady() {
    super.onReady();
  }

  var taskList = <Task>[].obs;

  Future<int> addTask({Task? task}) async {
    return await DatabaseCodes.insert(task);
  }

  //get all the data from table
  void getTasks() async {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> tasks = await DatabaseCodes.query();
    taskList.assignAll(tasks.map((data) => new Task.fromJson(data)).toList());
  }
}

db_make.dart (database creating file)
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import '../models/task.dart';

class DatabaseCodes {
  static Database? _db;
  static final int _version = 1;
  static final String _tableName = "tasks";

  static Future<void> initDb() async {
    if (_db != null) {
      return;
    }
    try {
      String _path = await getDatabasesPath() + 'tasks.db';
      _db = await openDatabase(
        _path,
        version: _version,
        onCreate: (db, version) {
          print("creating a new one");
          return db.execute(
            "CREATE TABLE $_tableName("
            "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            "title STRING, note TEXT, date STRING, "
            "startTime STRING, endTime STRING,"
            "remind INTEGER, repeat STRING, "
            "color INTEGER, "
            "isCompleted INTEGER)",
          );
        },
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  static Future<int> insert(Task? task) async {
    print("insert function called");
    return await _db?.insert(_tableName, task!.toJson()) ?? 1;
  }

  static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> query() async {
    print('query function called');
    return await _db!.query(_tableName);
  }
}


Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Why are you using MaterialApp in HomePagePass(), remove that because you are already passing it in parent. Material App internally wrap the widgets in Naviagtor widget. But when you have two Naviagtor wrap to each other it will make nesting. Same goes for add_task. And on btn click when you are navigating from one screen to another, due to nested route is throwing error.

Because i need dark-light mode. And i can provide the shortest method with it. Or do you know another methods ? Can you help me for it ?
